# CSV file opening error as "maximum number of rows has been exceeded "

Tags: csv, scrapy

I am working on Scrapy, i fetched the data from a web page and trying to stored them in a csv file.

Actually i had `2560` rows of data to be write to csv file.

When i tried to open the file in OpenOffice, i get this error:

```
The maximum number of rows has been exceeded. Excess rows were not imported.
```

I am able to open the file but i am getting only `600` rows and remaining rows are deleted.

How can i get Scrapy to download all the 2560 rows in to one csv file?

Comment: You should be more clear about the source of your problem/error. For example, that error message appears to come from OpenOffice's Calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your problem is just OpenOffice (or LibreOffice) refusing to load such a long .csv. The data itself should be okay- the remaining rows were simply not imported.

If you open up the file in a plain text editor (something like `vi` or `nano`), you should see that all your content is there.

Alternatively, you can try the following:

```
$ wc -l file.csv
```

The result should be 2560 (indicating that there are 2560 lines in the file).

Comment: :Yes you are right all the rows are storing in the file , when we open that with text editor its displaying with all the lines, but when we open with csv its not, but is there any solution for this to achieve this in csv file , i mean to open this in csv format only with all the rows

Comment: @shivakrishna ask LibreOffice or OpenOffice support about this -- it isn't a development question, and is thus off-topic here.