# In OpenOffice 3.3 why am I getting a "maximum number of rows has been exceeded" message?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I trying to open a .csv file generated by an Oracle SQL query in OpenOffice 3.3 and it is spitting back this message:

> The maximum number of rows has been exceeded. Excess rows were not
>   imported!

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879152/csv-file-opening-error-as-maximum-number-of-rows-has-been-exceeded) but it did not help. This is so strange because of 21,088 rows every single one loaded.

The more bizarre part is that some of the rows have been printed with proper delimitation and some haven't. In particular, seemingly random rows are truncated, including the first one, about the last 1000, and even the very last row that normally says "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed." just says "PL/SQL".

I have two databases identical in structure that I have been running the query on, and the other one works with no issues. I'm floored. Any ideas?

Comment: (1) You might had over-tagged your question since it would either be an issue in the extraction of the information from the DB or the uploading into OpenOffice. (2) The very first thing I would try (if possible) is to generate the same file from both DBs and compare them. (3) What happens if you delete from the input file, say, the first 10,000 rows and try to upload? Does it stop at the same record? (4) We may be able to be more helpful of you provide more info, including what you already tried.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where the error is. It is pulling out of an Oracle DB with an SQL query, spooling the data to a .csv, then opening it using OpenOffice.org Calc (hence the tags I used). When generating the file from the other database, it works exactly as expected. I tried changing the bad file to an .html and opened it in Firefox, and it had the same problems (but no error message this time). What might cause Oracle to spool incomplete lines from one instance to another?

Comment: Are you sure the select retrieves the result with missing lines? Did you try the query manually? Do you have a default limit to the number of returned records? Unless you have a manual/visual examination of the _in-between_ steps, you might end up chasing your own tail.

Comment: OpenOffice.org 3.3 is [five years old](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Product_Release#Released_OpenOffice.org_3.x.x).  Have you tried using Apache OpenOffice 4.1.2 or a recent version of LibreOffice?  However it sounds like there is some problem with the CSV file, so upgrading may not help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with 3.3. As awful as the situation is, I may not upgrade to anything else and am forced to use the tools I have :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I wasn't noticing that it was opening the file with the delimiter set to the space character. I do not know why it was giving that error message because all the data was still there (hidden pages over, it's a LONG string), but at the very least that solved the problem. Thank you for your help.